# How does a website post client-side scripting code examples without getting executed on client machine?

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, web

I am studying Security and wanted to know the general approach to retrieve and display code to client after it is safely encoded and stored in the database.

Comment: `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>` can display `<script>` normally with `<` and `>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is JS that will alert `Hello` :

```
<script>
 alert('Hello');
</script>
```

The above code can be displayed on a web page by replacing the `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt` :

```
&lt;script&gt;
 alert('Hello');
&lt;/script&gt;
```

The above will display as code, but won't execute on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Output using:

```
htmlspecialchars($output, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

If you are using a framework or template engine, they will inevitably have some sort of escape function or modifier to use from within a template which wraps this function.

See: https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars